# Foundation5 Stop Dropdown from Being clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation-5

When I hover over the dropdowns on:

[Website with Issue](http://sosfirstaid.ca/dev/courses/)

They do not open unless they are clicked. The website is built using Foundation5 (FoundationPress) and I am not able to figure out how to disable this behaviour in favour of having the dropdown appear on hover.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the hoverable dropdown options on the menu accessed through the `data-options` attribute. Similar convention with some of your content below as an example:

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="hover1" data-options="is_hover:true; hover_timeout:5000">Course Locations</a>

    <ul id="hover1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
      <li><a href="#">Brampton</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Burlington</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hampton</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">etc.</a></li>
    </ul>
```

You can set the `hover_timout` in milliseconds to delay closing after removing your mouse from the area.

Docs for this here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html